# datetime_select with zeroed minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I know that I can use the component parts of the date helpers, rather than the full
datetime_select, but I'm not sure how it would work as far as combining the params.

A bit of background, I'm creating an app for traffic monitoring where people can log traffic counts in 1 hour blocks. I'm presenting the user with a datetime_select so they can specify the start of the block, then later I'm calculating the end.

So I don't want people to be able to submit minutes or seconds, well seconds aren't shown with the helper so that's a start.

I've tried to zero it before the record is created with something like:

```
params[:result]['start(5i)'] = 0
```

which is the key that the development log shows rails is using for minutes. Unfortunately I get:

```
undefined method `empty?' for 0:Fixnum
```

I guess I could do this with some javascript, hide the minutes select box and remove all but the "00" option. I'd rather find a nice, clean solution if I can though.

Grateful for some tips. Happy to provide more information but not sure what else might be of use at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

params are Strings!  try this:

params[:result]['start(5i)'] = '0'

or this:

params[:result]['start(5i)'] = ''

Comment: Great, that works perfectly to zero out the minutes, now however I'm having trouble hiding the minutes select box. I thought I had found a fix on another question, but that doesn't actually work...I just got mixed up with all the selects on the page :D

Comment: The rails API suggests that using `:discard_minutes => true` should work, as should ommitting `:minutes` from the order hash. Unfortunately neither make a difference for me.

Comment: Ok, simple error, it's `:discard_minute => true`. Actually, I can set the `minute_step` to 60 which means that 00 is the only option. This automatically zeroes the minutes and also looks a bit cleaner. Taking out the minutes completely looked a bit strange.